# How to use "link to cell" in Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

There is a "link to cell" button on the cells in Colab, which is located just right to "move cell up" and "move cell down" menu.

I understand that it gives a link to the cell. But I don't see any good example for this function.

There is a similar question in stack overflow, but the answer does not help.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15UNc0vGlqgq2xT6-XF-mfeLGgJhZDfQJ#scrollTo=FTL2EVjmxZHa&line=1&uniqifier=1

Comment: Would you mind sharing that 'similar question in stack overflow' ? Referring to something we cannot inspect does not help to know what you know, which in turn helps to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

My friends and I use Colab to share projects and ideas. When someone is explaining a method *M* (to ask for insights or fresh ideas) he needs to point out such source code section. A direct link is better than copy/paste first line of *M* and ask your friend (coworker) to use Ctrl+F to search it. There are several large projects and you don't need (or can) to keep track of every written method.

Comment: That's OK... Granted, and might have been an advanced solution in the 1980's. 
But isn't it undermining technology (especially when @Rub's Rub has noted it with exceptional clarity, and to the utmost convenience of peers to just clicking hyperlinks instead of Ctrl+F's or typing in texts and Enter's and remembering what was there, and finally verifying-- even with lots of uncertainty in every step) !

Comment: kudos to you @ParthaD. for comparing two answers that are more than two years apart and undermine the oldest just because. Remember that the OP asked for usages examples not banal criticism.

Comment: No offence meant @Eloy Pérez Torres. I was actually searching for a different solution (_**scrolling** to the linked section_, rather than _**opening** the link in a new tab/window_), which Rub happened to answer. Apologies for my hurried mistake. And literal thanks for pointing that out. I'll be more cautious in future before criticising any answer.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine something like this

[image]

The code may have many levels, and cells within those levels.

[image]

If you want to have direct links (not necessarily for a top section) at the beginning of the document (or anywhere), this feature (link to cell) helps you to do that.

---

On the right of the Markdown cell, click on 'link to cell'.

[image]

You will get a URL like this...

```
[Section A](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Y...tE#scrollTo=em3...OMY)
```

---

**Note:** For the links to really 'take' you to another section instead of opening another tab/window focused on that section, you need to use them like this **in Markdown cells**

- Delete everything in the copied hyperlink till `#scroll=...`

  [image: Delete everything till #scroll=]

  so, you'll be left with only something of this sort :

  ```
  [Section A](#scrollTo=em3...OMY)
  ```

  And this hyperlink, once clicked, should *scroll* you to your desired location, rather than *opening* a new window or tab.

Comment: This answer would be improved by indicating that the user should first go to the cell being referenced(ie. the one to scroll to) and then click copy link, to retreive that cell location's URL. Then remove the characters of the URL up to "#scroll[..]" and paste that into the parenthesis.  Otherwise I found your answer unclear where the scrollTo unqiue identifier was generated.

Comment: While @ enjoi4life411 may be right, I highly prefer the style of @Partha D. that instead of asking for a better answer, edited my answer making it clearer & more complete for those unfamiliar with Colab / anchor links.